# How Java synchronize updates thread value?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have next code:

```
boolean signal;

@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!signal){
                // empty loop body
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    signal = true;
    thread.join();
}
```

It runs infinity loop due to creation of local copy of `signal` variable in thread. I know that I can fix it by making my `signal` variable  `volatile`. But also loop can successfully exit if add `synchronized` block inside my loop (even empty):

```
boolean signal;

@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!signal){
                synchronized (this) {

                }
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    signal = true;
    thread.join();
}
```

How `synchronized` updates my `signal` value inside thread?

Comment: It would be perfectly legal for your second program to never exit - your JVM/CPU architecture seems to apply a stronger memory model than what the JLS requires.

Comment: Interesting read: https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/

Comment: He shows a closely related example in https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#wishful-unobserved-sync

Answer (score 1):

Synchronized does not updates the signal value itself, it basically just places a couple of flags to avoid two threads use the same object at the same time; something like: MonitorEnter and MonitorExit.

The first one locks the object, and the second one releases.

Take a look at the following article: [how-the-java-virtual-machine-performs-thread-synchronization](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076971/java-concurrency/how-the-java-virtual-machine-performs-thread-synchronization.html).

Please notice the article is very old; but as far as I understand the logic behind remains.

Comment: I know that, but why adding of synchronized block to loop updates signal variable in my second example?

Comment: Because the one without synchronized is a selfish thread; it means; it will stop until finishes its work; any thread can become a selfish thread if inside the loop it does not have a yield/sleep/Blocking Operation such I/O

Now, when you placed the synchronized you make your selfish thread to be not selfish, since there is a blocking operation on the object "signal"

The behavior itself depends a lot on the Infrastructure where you run it; but basically you have two threads there 1) main 2) thread and since the second is selfish it won't let main to continue...